# Nhibernate mapping at run time

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am developing a site in which nhibernate is using. that is working fine for static mapping. but problem that i apply this application on existing database. so is there any way that mapping of classes took place at run time. i mean user provide tables and column names for mapping. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can use NHibernate for that. I'm assuming that you want use NHibernate for mapping any field of any database if the user show you how to make the mapping for filling a compiled object. But i don't think you could do this. But I think that there could be a workaround using views. I'll post it on an answer.

Comment: You will need an ORM that supports dynamic (unless the POCO class exists - as Andrew Shepherd's mentioned bellow). Here is a good example: http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/104/PetaPoco-Not-So-Poco-or-adding-support-for-dynamic

Answer (score 4):

From your question I interpret you saying that the POCO classes exists, but you don't know the table or column names at build time.

So, if you already had this class:

```
public class MyGenericClass 
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You could bind it to a table and columns at runtime:

```
 string tableName; // Set somewhere else by user input
 string idColumnName; // Set somewhere else by user input
 string titleColumnName; // Set somewhere else by user input

 var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
 configuration.Configure();

 var mapper = new NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.ModelMapper();

 mapper.Class<MyGenericClass>(
           classMapper =>
           {
                classMapper.Table(tableName);
                classMapper.Id(
                      myGenericClass => myGenericClass.Id,
                      idMapper =>
                      {
                          idMapper.Column(idColumnName);
                          idMapper.Generator(Generators.Identity);
                      }
                 );
                 classMapper.Property(c => c.Title,
                                      propertyMapper =>
                                      {
                                          propertyMapper.Column(titleColumnName);
                                      }
                                     );
           }
 );

 ISessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
 ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(); 

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Now we can run an SQL query over this newly specified table
 //
 List<MyGenericClass> items = session.QueryOver<MyGenericClass>().List();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that could be possibly with NHibernate, but you could use a workaround.
You could use a view instead a table for the NHibernate mapping.

And in runtime, you could create that View or update it with the especified user mapping you need.

For example, you define a mapping in NHibernate to a view named `ViewMapped` with two columns `Name` and `Mail`.
And in the other hand, the user has a table with three columns `Name`, `SecondName`, `EMail`.
you can create a view on runtime with the following select:

```
(SELECT Name + ' ' + SecondName as Name, EMail as Mail FROM tableName) AS ViewMapped
```

I hope that helps you, or at least leads you to a solution.